# Heroku: "currently in use by another app" when I added my domain

Tags: redirect, heroku

I want to redirect my domain "cultiva.bilsa.com" to Heroku app "cultiva.herokuapp.com". Some reason, when I want to add this domain, Heroku said to me "cultiva.bilsa.com currently in use by another app". I have never been added so far. I follow [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) page and I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: I'd recommend getting in touch with Heroku support to see what's going on.

Comment: We're having the same issue as well.  It just started happening for us yesterday.

Comment: I opened a ticked today in Heroku. I hope they explain what happen.

Comment: @pegatron, would you mind sharing how you resolved the issue, it might be useful for others in the same situation.

Comment: This was really my fault. I had added this domain on my other Heroku account unconsciously. I have just realized. I removed and could add yet.

Answer (score 8):

You can determine all of the domains you are using in an account with the following bash one liner:

```
heroku apps > heroku_apps_list; for i in `cat heroku_apps_list`; do heroku domains --app $i ; done
```

This is useful if you have many apps and many different domains on Heroku.

Comment: This worked very well for me, but because many of my apps are in teams I had to pass the `--all` flag to `heroku apps`. If you're not seeing the apps you expect, try that.

Answer (score 5):

Like Eric said the domain was already registred, and never released. You have to use the release tool to release your domain, and after that associate the app to your domain:

https://tools.heroku.support/domain-release

You'll need to be able to verify your ownership of this domain adding a TXT record.

Answer (score 1):

The domain legitimately was already registered with a heroku app. You can determine this by calling `heroku domains`.